# Regex for matching url prefix

Tags: regex, url, prefix

I want to delete the Google prefix in all URLs.

```
<a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=en&usg=YFo&url=http://www.goo.tv/gd/2015/0509/735557.html

dfgdfgdfgdfgdf9

<a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=en&usg=AFQjCNFUS_UVkd9L-r7g&clid=c3878e0698331&cid=5213281008&ei=5DFNVJ4eymQLmyYFo&url=http://www.goo.tv/gd/2015/0509/735557.html
```

I want to remove `http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=en&blalba....url=`
this Google prefix, so that it only retains the real URL.

I tried the regex, but it doesn't match each prefix, it matches all content 
`<a href="(http:\/\/news.google.com/news/url\?([\s\S]*)&url=)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Lazy Quantifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy):

```
<a href="(http:\/\/news.google.com\/news\/url\?([\s\S]*?)&url=)
```

Your regex did not worked because it was greedy(*), and took the match until the last &url= found. Lazy quantifiers(*?) stops at first match found, which is the expected behavior for your case.